# LaTeX pdf form checkbox loses FieldValue if checked and then unchecked

Tags: hyperref, pdf, forms

I came across strange behaviour of a `CheckBox` in a PDF form created using LaTeX and `hyperref`.

I created a form such as the MWE below using LaTeX, which has a checkbox which is initially checked. I used [pdftk](https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/) to strip out the form fields, where the `FieldValue` was indicated as `Yes` (see below). (I was under the impression that all PDF form fields store the field data in the `FieldValue` parameter).

I then opened the PDF file, unchecked the `CheckBox` and saved it again. Using `pdftk` again, `FieldValue` entry disappeared (see below)!

This happens whether the initial state is unchecked (in which case the parameter reads `FieldValue: Off`), then checked and then unchecked again, but the `FieldValue` parameter always disappears after the last unchecking. I have written code to look for the `FieldValue` parameter, but this falls over if the checkbox is unchecked and the `FieldValue` parameter disappears. Any suggestions?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\begin{Form}

\CheckBox[checked=true]{My checkbox}

\end{Form}
\end{document}

Initial output with checkbox checked (stripping out fields using pdftk):
---
FieldType: Button
FieldName: My checkbox
FieldFlags: 0
FieldValue: Yes
FieldJustification: Left
FieldStateOption: Yes

Output after checkbox unchecked:
---
FieldType: Button
FieldName: My checkbox
FieldFlags: 0
FieldJustification: Left
FieldStateOption: Yes
FieldStateOption: Off
```

Comment: which pdftk command do you use? And which pdf viewer did you use to save the pdf?

Comment: `pdftk MWE_checkbox.pdf dump_data_fields output MWE_checkbox_0.txt` for the pdftk output, where MWE_checkbox.pdf is the input file and MWE_checkbox_0.txt has the form field data. I have used Adobe Acrobat DC, Adobe Acrobat Reader DC as well as PDF-XChange to test the checking and unchecking of the CheckBox (saving in each of these and then running pdftk).

Comment: Do you have any example from checkboxes where the field is not lost after saving with the pdf viewer? If the viewer does it always, then hyperref will not be able to prevent it.

Comment: No, I have tried variations of the process described above, but the result is always the same, whether starting with the `CheckBox` checked or unchecked, exporting the form fields before checking and unchecking etc. If the `CheckBox` is initially created and it is unchecked, then the `FieldValue` is initially there, indicated as `FieldValue: Off`.

Comment: That was not my question. Did you try with some form not created by hyperref?

Comment: It seems it is not the behaviour of `hyperref` that is the issue. I created a form in Adobe Acrobat DC with an unchecked `CheckBox`. It did not have a `FieldValue` entry. Checking it generates a `FieldValue: Yes` entry when exporting the fields with `pdftk`, while unchecking it again results in no `FieldValue` entry.